# On the Density of Deficient Odd Numbers and Abundant Integers

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of the divisors* of $x$.  If $\sigma(x) < 2x$, then $x$ is said to be **deficient**, while if $\sigma(x) > 2x$, $x$ is said to be **abundant**.  (Of course, when $\sigma(x) = 2x$, $x$ is called a **perfect number**.)

In [Advanced Problem 5967](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318269), C. W. Anderson (The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 82, No. 10 (Dec., 1975), pp. 1018-1020) computed that the density of **deficient odd numbers** is at least
$$\dfrac{48 - 3{\pi}^2}{32 - {\pi}^2} \approx 0.831.$$

[Behrend](https://eudml.org/doc/204583), [Wall et al](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1972-26-119/S0025-5718-1972-0327700-7/S0025-5718-1972-0327700-7.pdf), [Deleglise](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1048515661) and subsequently [Kobayashi](https://math.dartmouth.edu/theses/grad/2010/kobayashi.pdf) computed ever-sharper bounds for the density $A(2)$ of **abundant integers**.  I give Deleglise's bounds here:
$$0.2474 < A(2) < 0.2480.$$

In

> Kanold, H. J., Uber die Dichten der Mengen der vollkommenen und der befreundeten Zahlen, Math. Z., vol 61, (1954) pp 180–185,

Kanold showed that the density of perfect numbers is $0$.

Since

> **Density of all numbers** $=$ **Density of even deficient numbers** $+$ **Density of odd deficient numbers** $+$ **Density of abundant numbers** $+$ **Density of perfect numbers**,

and since

> **Density of even deficient numbers** $\geq 0$,

we have the contradiction
$$1 > 0 + 0.831 + 0.2474 + 0 \approx 1.0784.$$

Here is my question:

> > Does this **apparent contradiction** imply that there is an ERROR *in one of the cited papers above*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the density of odd deficient numbers cannot be more than $0.5$ in the sense that you interpreted it. Thus Anderson's result must mean that the density of deficient numbers *within the odd numbers* is at least $0.831$. This interpretation fits well with what is visible on the first page of the paper that you linked to. This would resolve the contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer, joriki!  I myself was kinda worried about Anderson's result, not until this answer of yours enlightened me!  Again, my profuse thanks.  =)